# VS Code error: The terminal process failed to launch: Path to shell executable "zsh" is not a file or a symlink

Tags: terminal, zsh, visual-studio-code, alacritty

I'm having this problem everytime I `ctrl` + `j` to open the integrated terminal. I'm on Arch using with ZSH and my default terminal is Alacritty.
My current settings.json file is:

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Dracula",
    "redhat.telemetry.enabled": false,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "editor.fontFamily": "'Hack Nerd Font'",
    "editor.fontSize": 16,
    "terminal.external.linuxExec": "alacritty",
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "zsh",
    "emmet.showSuggestionsAsSnippets": true,
    "editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": true,
    "terminal.explorerKind": "external",
    "auto-close-tag.activationOnLanguage": [
        "*"
    ],
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "javascript": "javascriptreact",
        "html.erb": "html"
    },
    "material-icon-theme.activeIconPack": "react",
}
```

Any idea on how to solve this message? I cannot open the integrated terminal

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I found a solution. Adding this to my settings.json solved the problem:

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
        "bash": {
          "path": "bash"
        },
        "zsh": {
          "path": "/usr/bin/zsh"
        }
},
```