# Can't create new integrated terminal(local) for mac on VSCode when connected to remote linux computer with ssh

Tags: linux, macos, visual-studio-code, ssh, terminal

I have VSCode connected to a host with ssh. I wanted to also open a local terminal in vscode so that I can edit local files with VSCode.
The error I get: The terminal process failed to launch: Path to shell executable "/usr/bin/zsh" does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68956079/vs-code-error-the-terminal-process-failed-to-launch-path-to-shell-executable) led me to a solution.

I searched `terminal.integrated.profiles` in VSCode settings to find the proper settings.json file. And found the `terminal.integrated.profiles.linux` section (my local terminal I am trying to open is on Mac but the remote I am sshing to is Linux and it seems that changing this setting for Linux rather than OSX fixes my issue) and changed the path for zsh just like the other answer.

However my path was different. I did `where zsh` on my Mac to find out where zsh was and changed the path to that (in my case `where zsh` was `/bin/zsh`)